# how to call soap service from the response of rest service?

Tags: node.js, soap

i am trying to call soap service after the execution of Rest service
**Explanation**:
i am getting the response from the Rest service,in that response i got username and password, i need to post that username and password (in body) to soap service to get the response (o/p). I tried it in runscope, got the correct response.
In nodejs using content-type:'application/json' for Rest service, but for Soap service content-type:'text/xml', how to use these two at a time?, Even i saw some links but didn't get correct solution,
**Example like this**:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var args = {FromCurrency: 'USD', ToCurrency: 'INR'};
var url = "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL";
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.ConversionRate(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Hussian - are you saying that you are able to perform both the REST and SOAP calls successfully using Runscope, or just the first?

Comment: @mansilladev soap service response i got succeesfully in Runscope